# Any HTML tags inside of tooltip cause basic tooltip to close on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, mouseover, fade

I'm new to jQuery, in fact any kind of AJAX / JavsScript (although not new to PHP, xHTML and CSS). Anyway I'm trying to achieve a "tooltip-like" effect, where I can hover over a div...the new div fades in above it and then when I exit the div the "tooltip" fades out.

So here's the basic jQuery I've managed to scrap together reading the odd guide here and there:

```
$(function()
{
    $('#sn-not-logged-in').hover(function()
    {
        $('#sn-not-logged-in-hover').fadeIn('medium');
    });

    $('#sn-not-logged-in-hover').mouseout(function()
    {
        $('#sn-not-logged-in-hover').fadeOut('medium');
    });

});
```

Problem is if I put "any" html tag inside the div that hovers in, the second you roll over it the div fades back out.

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Updated for Comments

Just switching your events to `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout` and `mousenter` instead of `hover` will fix the issue for your markup, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#sn-not-logged-in').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#sn-not-logged-in-hover').fadeIn('medium');
  });
  $('#sn-not-logged-in-hover').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#sn-not-logged-in-hover').fadeOut('medium');
  });
});
```

---

### Previous Answer

Change your [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) up a bit, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#sn-not-logged-in').hover(function() {
    $('#sn-not-logged-in-hover').fadeIn('medium');
  }, function() {
     $('#sn-not-logged-in-hover').fadeOut('medium');
  });
});
```

[`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) executes on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` (the first and second function you provide, respectively), so it's calling the `fadeIn()` already overlapping a bit already.

The `mouseout` however, fires **even when entering a child**, `mouseenter` which `.hover()` uses won't.  So what's currently actually causing your current issue...moving the mouse onto the `<img>` tag inside, won't be a problem :)

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your quick answer.

The information was useful, although didn't solve my problem - actually made it worse - I feel this is more down to my poor explanation of the problem as opposed to your response. 

Rather than expect you to guess where I'm at, I've knocked up a quick demo: http://christianbullock.com/demo/

Hopefully it should be easier to see my problem. When you hover over the blue button, tab, whatever...it fades in the new div. I've used CSS positioning to make this div overlap the blue button...so I guess the browser doesnt know i've entered the new div.

Comment: @Christian - Try the updated answer, good job with the page, very helpful :)

Comment: Nick, you're a legend - solved my problem :). 

I'll be back once I have more rep to +1 your answers. Thanks a million. ;)